# How to destroy an object in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have platforms in my game that I want to destroy as they pass through a boundary object. I can't seem to get it working.

Here is the boundary object in the panel view:

[image]

Here is the code attached to my boundary object:

```
public class DestroyByBoundary : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy (other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

And here is the platform object I am trying to destroy:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to set isTrigger in EdgeCollider to true?

Comment: The problem was I was mixing 2D and 3D components. It should be OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other).. I also had to change the Box Collider on the Boundary gameObject to Box Collider2D.